# How to handle application config files and custom built java classes

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

In the infrastructure I've inherited, the guys use jenkins and maven to construct jars and config files.

So, jenkins checks out some code, then maven builds something. Jenkins post build task then copies files from mavens target directory and copies them to a "build share" (eeks), for example

Source

```
**/target/*.jar
```

Destination

```
releases/env_name/project/lib
```

Source

```
**/target/classes/some-service.xml
```

Destination

```
releases/env_name/project/conf
```

I dare say this is not ideal.

In the new provisioning project, the jars from the build, are deployed into Nexus. In turn, I then use the maven rpm plugin to build RPMs using GAVs to identify which jars are packaged. I haven't captured the config files.

Could I publish the config files to Nexus? Yes they're small, but still artifacts. They would also have a maven snapshot or release coordinate, which could fit in with my releases. I have not tried, but I imagine I can add a section to my existing RPM build pom so that the desired plain text files are uploaded to Nexus when I run mvn deploy.

Some of the files require modification post deployment to suit an environment - this adds further head ache to this.

The poms that define the RPMs will also grow significantly in length. Not a problem per se, if I can ascertain this is the right way.

The question: How have others managed jars and config files deployment in a multi-environment set up?

Comment: Doh. Can't do that. Can't publish multiple GAVs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking how others have done it, I will say how I do, which may or may not be appropriate in your situation.

- The binaries (.jar or whatnot) are build by Jenkins from the source code in SVN.
- The SVN source code has configuration files, but most of the time, those are configured for DEV or Local environments. I let them have it there so that developers' local builds can be simple, but really as far as I am concerned they don't exist.
- The SVN also has a separate location (not accessible by DEV, only by Release Managers and Systems teams), and this location contains configuration files for all environments (including DEV environment, when deployed from the CI server)
- Since we have a lot of environment specific settings, it makes sense to keep separate copies of each environment.
- If a new configuration parameter is added, it is merged from DEV config files all the way to PROD, just like other source code changes are merged, with the exception that only RM or Systems team can do it.
- The deployment process (in our case a shell script, but could be anything) takes care of pulling the correct configuration files from SVN and pushing them, along with binaries, to the remote server. Once server is deployed, the "in-jar" configuration is wholly replaced by the configuration files that came from SVN.
- I organize the configuration file by ENV, then by TYPE, for example: `QA/WEB`, `QA/API` and then `PROD/WEB`, `PROD/API`. So I don't have to maintain configuration files for each remote machine.
- However there are times when configuration is specific to the remote machine, such as an IP address of the machine. In these cases, the SVN configuration file contains a token, like `[local_ip]`. When the deployment script pushes this file to remote server, it then knows to replace the token with real IP of the remote machine